# Воспроизвести аудио из интернета

Tags: wpf

Как средствами WPF воспроизвести аудио файл из интернета?

Такой пример не работает.

```
private MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       player.Open(new Uri("https://....music.mp3", UriKind.Relative));
       player.Play();
    }
```

Comment: Ссылки HTTP воспроизводятся а HTTPS не хотят.

Comment: Пример ссылки приведите откуда не воспроизводится.